# Where can I find the gradient calculation implementations for each operation in tensorflow ?

Tags: tensorflow

I went through the source code and the gradient function implemented in this python file

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py

But still I couldn't find any python api for calculating gradients ?
What is this process ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from my code where I'm taking the gradient of my loss function with respect to the activations of the last layer of my network and then passing that to tensorboard in the form of a single scalar value and as a histogram.

```
gradient_a = tf.gradients(loss, [0], [3]), [out_layer_a], name='gradient_position_a')
tf.summary.scalar('mean_gradient_magnitude_a', tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(self.gradient_a)))
tf.summary.histogram('gradient_magnitude_a', gradient_a)
```

If you want to output the gradient just fetch gradient_a in your call to `session.run([loss, gradient_a], feed_dict={...})`

Comment: No this is not I am asking. I am asking whether you have any clue where tf has implemented it's auto differentiation.

Comment: When you say "where tensorflow has implemented its auto differentiation" what do you mean? These gradients are the result of the underlying auto differentiation mechanism built into each op of course. But I'm not following your comment very clearly, can you elaborate?

Comment: Well you have mentioned it in your comment " These gradients are the result of the underlying auto differentiation mechanism built into each op of course"

Comment: For each op tensorflow has implemented it's differentiation. When we run Optimizer.minimize(loss) it willl again load to the graph as a gradient op and then backtrack while applying gradients with chain rule.
So I went to the source code minimize function , and from their I was directed to def Gradients() in this file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py (line-390). Inside that function there is this this  "op" thing(line-466) which I cannot backtrack the path after that.